# Why dont the Gradle understand that file is Groovy?

Tags: gradle, groovy

> I try to exeute the example on testing in the gradle guidehttps://guides.gradle.org/testing-gradle-plugins/
>
> The build build.gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/integration-test.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/functional-test.gradle"

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    localGroovy()
    testCompile ('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.7')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5') 
    testImplementation gradleTestKit()
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2'

}
```

> And my functional-test.gradle file looks like this
>   s

```
ourceSets {
    functionalTest {
        groovy.srcDir file('src/functTest/groovy')
        resources.srcDir file('src/functTest/resources')
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
    }
}

task functionalTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the functional tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
    mustRunAfter test, integrationTest
}

check.dependsOn functionalTest

// tag::source-set-config[]
gradlePlugin {
    testSourceSets sourceSets.functionalTest
}
```

> The functional test for the plugin looks like this

```
package com.steinko.groovy.sample.http

import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TempDir
import spock.lang.Specification
import java.io.File
import static org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome.SUCCESS

class UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest extends Specification {

    @TempDir 
    private File testProjectDir;

    private File buildFile;

    def setup() {
        buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')
        buildFile << """
            plugins {
                id 'org.gradle.sample.urlverifier'
            }
        """
    }

    def "can successfully configure URL through extension and verify it"() {
        buildFile << """
            verification {
                url = 'https://www.google.com/'
            }
        """

        when:
        def result = GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root)
            .withArguments('verifyUrl')
            .withPluginClasspath()
            .build()

        then:
        result.output.contains("Successfully resolved URL 'https://www.google.com/'")
        result.task(":verifyUrl").outcome == SUCCESS
    }
}
```

> When I run the task gradle functionalTest I get following error:
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:1: error: ';' expected
>   package com.steinko.groovy.sample.http
>                                         ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:3: error: ';' expected
>   import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner
>                                                ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:4: error: ';' expected
>   import org.junit.jupiter.api.TempDir
>                                       ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:5: error: ';' expected
>   import spock.lang.Specification
>                                  ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:6: error: ';' expected
>   import java.io.File
>                      ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:7: error: ';' expected
>   import static org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome.SUCCESS
>                                                              ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:17: error: unclosed character literal
>           buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')
>                                              ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:17: error: unclosed character literal
>           buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')
>                                                           ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:17: error: not a statement
>           buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')
>                                                    ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:18: error: unclosed string literal
>           buildFile << """
>                          ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:18: error: not a statement
>           buildFile << """
>                     ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:19: error: not a statement
>               plugins {
>               ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:19: error: ';' expected
>               plugins {
>                      ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:20: error: unclosed character literal
>                   id 'org.gradle.sample.urlverifier'
>                      ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:20: error: not a statement
>                   id 'org.gradle.sample.urlverifier'
>                   ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:20: error: illegal line end in character literal
>                   id 'org.gradle.sample.urlverifier'
>                                                    ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:20: error: not a statement
>                   id 'org.gradle.sample.urlverifier'
>                                        ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:22: error: unclosed string literal
>           """
>             ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:22: error: not a statement
>           """
>           ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:25: error:  expected
>       def "can successfully configure URL through extension and verify it"() {
>          ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:26: error: unclosed string literal
>           buildFile << """
>                          ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:26: error: not a statement
>           buildFile << """
>                     ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:27: error: not a statement
>               verification {
>               ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:27: error: ';' expected
>               verification {
>                           ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:28: error: unclosed character literal
>                   url = 'https://www.google.com/'
>                         ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:29: error: illegal start of statement
>               }
>               ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:30: error: unclosed string literal
>           """
>             ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:30: error: not a statement
>           """
>           ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:35: error: unclosed character literal
>               .withArguments('verifyUrl')
>                              ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:33: error: variable declaration not allowed here
>           def result = GradleRunner.create()
>               ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:35: error: unclosed character literal
>               .withArguments('verifyUrl')
>                                        ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:35: error: not a statement
>               .withArguments('verifyUrl')
>                                ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:37: error: ';' expected
>               .build()
>                       ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:40: error: ';' expected
>           result.output.contains("Successfully resolved URL 'https://www.google.com/'")
>                                                                                        ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:41: error: not a statement
>           result.task(":verifyUrl").outcome == SUCCESS
>                                             ^
>   /Users/steinkorsveien/Development/TestWorkSpace/HowToTest/src/functTest/groovy/com/steinko/groovy/sample/http/UrlVerifierPluginFunctionalTest.java:41: error: ';' expected
>           result.task(":verifyUrl").outcome == SUCCESS
>                                                       ^
>   36 errors
>   startup failed:
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

1 error

> Task :compileFunctionalTestGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileFunctionalTestGroovy'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
Steins-MacBook-Air:HowToTest steinkorsveien$ 
>

> I looks like that the compile sees the file as Java Code
>   How do I fix is so I can get the groovy code compiled?

Comment: you have to rename your file `*.java` to `*.groovy`, then compiler will know that this is a groovy file

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the file *.java to *.groovy then is works